# Jenkins selecting unselected rows from Datasource Step

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I have test cases with DataSource step with many values. But I want to execute the tests with only few of the values from dataSource. So I selected the ones which I will executing the tests with. This works perfectly fine on local Ready API. But when the same test is executed from Jenkins, it seems the tests are executed on all the rows, including the unselected rows.

Is there any solution or setting I need or any suggestion.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't particularly clear, but based on what you've wrote, I can try and help.

When you configure a datasource, SoapUI will run your test for each row, so I'm not sure how you're selecting a subset.  If you're using Excel as your source, you could create another sheet that contains the subset, but you'd need to update your datasource to point at the other sheet.

If Jenkins is not running what you'd expect, I would look at ensuring you have properly committed your changes ready for Jenkins to pick up.

In each of my data-driven tests, I used the first column of the row as a value to decide whether to run or not.  I use, true, false and stop.  In my test, I have a groovy step immediately after the datasource step.  This groovy script reads the first col of the row and based on the value will then decide what to do.

```
def runTest = context.expand( '${DataSource#runTest}' );
def testNumber = context.expand( '${SiteDataSource#testNumber}' );

if (runTest.toUpperCase().equals("FALSE")) {
    log.info("Test Number ${testNumber} has been disabled.  Jumping to next test..");   
    testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Scenario End - Groovy Script");
} else if (runTest.toUpperCase().equals("TRUE")) {  
    log.info("Running this scenario....");      
} else if (runTest.toUpperCase().equals("STOP")) {
    log.info("Stopping testing at this row ${testNumber}.....");
    testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Test Ends - Groovy Script");
}
```

So, if true, I do nothing as the next step is the first real step in my test.

If false, I jump to the end of the test steps immediately prior to the datasource loop as I want the test to loop back round and see if the next one needs to be run.

If stop, then I jump to the very last step in the test, which is after the datasource loop step.

The 'Scenario End' and 'Test Ends' groovy scripts contain nothing other than a log-info message.

Comment: Thanks Chris I'll give it a try!